# Optimize performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

```
Select * 
from #temp1 
    join #temp2 on #temp2.mdx <> replace(#temp2.mdx,#temp1.mdx,'')
```

Above query takes around 30 mins to execute.  I want to reduce this time.

- `#temp1` contains 100 000 records
- `#temp2` contains 4 000 records
- Both `#temp1.mdx` and `#temp2.mdx` are `varchar(max)` columns.

temp2.mdx is a formula like `subprocess[1].dp[2]/subprocess[1].dp[5]` and this can be upto any length. temp1.mdx contains a part of that formula.

I want get all rows of #temp1.mdx against each formula of #temp2.mdx like if temp1.mdx contains

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

and temp2.mdx contains

1. A/b
2. A/C*d

by above logic I will get 2 rows for a/b and 3 rows for a/b*d because when you replace A from A/b with '' then it is not equal to A/b and this way you will find all the rows which are used in that formula.

Max len of temp2.mdx is 10213.

I am trying to run this query on my local machine which is 3.1ghz along with 8gb ram. I have not tried it on the actual server yet.

Comment: Are these actual temp tables? Or did you just set it up that way for the example?

Comment: **Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).**

Answer (score 6):

This type of query will never perform well:

```
Select * 
from #temp1 join #temp2 on #temp2.mdx <> replace(#temp2.mdx,#temp1.mdx,'')
```

But you can make it perform better if you understand why it won't perform well. SQL Server has three options to physically implement that join: hash join, merge join, and loop join. Both hash join and merge join require at least one equality condition in the join that is always true, so those are ineligible for this query. If you try to force them you'll get an error. So you must do a loop join, but there's no way to create an index which you can use to do a seek on the inner side of the nested loop join. Essentially, you are requiring SQL Server to do a cross join of the two tables and to evaluate the join predicate once for each combination of rows. For your table sizes you'll need to calculate the predicate 400 million times.

So what can you do about it? You can improve performance by making the join predicate as cheap as possible to calculate (since you'll need to do it 400 million times) and by encouraging SQL Server to execute your query in parallel. The query optimizer is biased against parallel plans for queries of this type.

Let's start with reducing the cost of the join predicate. Does `temp1.mdx` always fit in a `VARCHAR(8000)`? The documentation for `[REPLACE][1]` says the following:

> string_pattern Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of
>   a character or binary data type. string_pattern cannot be an empty
>   string (''), and must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits
>   on a page.

So as if you might be getting wrong results. Setting that aside, the `REPLACE` function means that you need to process the entire `#temp2.mdx` string each time. You can't quit early if you find a match right away. Intuitively, it feels like the wrong function for this kind of task. You can use LIKE instead, but you need to be careful with automatic conversions to `VARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
Select * 
from #temp1 
    join #temp2 on #temp2.mdx LIKE CAST('%' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + #temp1.mdx + CAST('%' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

I don't know what your data set looks like, but on my machine this shaves off 33% of the runtime. You can do even better if you can use `CHARINDEX`, but that only works if `#temp1.mdx` can be cast as a `VARCHAR(8000)` without losing data.

```
Select * 
from #temp1 
    join #temp2 on charindex(#temp1.mdx, #temp2.mdx) > 0
```

That syntax saves 50% of the runtime compared to the original query. If the original query takes 30 minutes to execute and does 400 million comparisons that kind of change can add up.

All of the queries naturally run with `MAXDOP 1` on my machine:

[image]

This happens because parallel plans don't reduce costs on the inner side of nested loops. If you really need to improve performance you can consider tricking SQL Server into using a [parallel plan](http://dataeducation.com/next-level-parallel-plan-forcing-an-alternative-to-8649/). This type of query is very suited to parallelism despite the optimizer's costing model. I'm going to use the undocumented trace flag 8649 which is not safe for production use:

```
Select * 
from #temp1 
    join #temp2 on charindex(#temp1.mdx, #temp2.mdx) > 0
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);
```

On an otherwise not-busy 4 CPU server you could see the query run 4X faster compared to before. Putting everything together you might see a speedup of 8X. Perhaps your query which took 30 minutes will now take closer to 4 minutes.

There may be some tricks you can employ around not selecting all columns, table definitions, and spools. Can't say more without more information.

Comment: When using `replace()` the second parameter `#temp1.mdx` is implicitly converted to `varchar(8000)` so if the replace version of the query used by OP returns the correct result you can safely assume that all values in `#temp1.mdx` can be cast as a `varchar(8000)` without data loss.

Comment: @mikael thats correct temp1.mdx can be fit into varchar(8000)

Comment: @joe it did not help at all i used both the queries (like as well as charindex)  but none of them gives any improvement

Answer (score 2):

I think attempting to optimise this query "as is" is a mistake for two reasons:

1. It is not a scalable approach - what if you have 1 million formulas next week or 10 million the week after?  The approach you are using will not scale even with a bit of tuning.
2. It potentially returns incorrect results - if your formula component is a substring of another then you get a hit, eg if you wanted to search a formula for components `subprocess` and one of your formula components was `sub` you would get a false result.

Therefore you **must change your approach**.  You mention you cannot split the string "because the formula is not as simple" - please post some more realistic formulas to represent this.

I have used some dummy Excel formulas in this simple demonstration of an approach to this problem.  This which will run on SQL Server 2017 or Azure SQL DB uses the new functions `TRANSLATE` and `STRING_SPLIT` for effective formula splitting.  The list of characters used for splitting could easily be extended.  This entire script (including dummy data generation) runs in about 5 seconds on my laptop whereas your original query ran for 7+ minutes on the same data.  Please work through the script and see if you can adapt the approach for your actual data.

```
-- SQL 2017 (or Azure SQL DB) only
USE tempdb
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.formulas
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.formulaComponents
GO

-- PART OF THAT FORMULA; 100,000 records
CREATE TABLE dbo.formulaComponents (
    fcId    INT IDENTITY(1,1000) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    mdx     VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE CLUSTERED
)

-- FORMULA: 4,000 records
CREATE TABLE dbo.formulas (
    fId     INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    mdx     VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO


-- Generate some formula components which look a bit like Excel refs; just for the demo
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 1 x
UNION ALL
SELECT x + 1
FROM cte
WHERE x < 9999
), letters AS (
SELECT x, CHAR(x) y
FROM cte
WHERE x Between 65 And 90
)
INSERT INTO dbo.formulaComponents ( mdx )
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100000 l.y + CAST( c.x AS VARCHAR(10) )
FROM cte c CROSS JOIN letters l
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )


INSERT INTO dbo.formulaComponents ( mdx )
VALUES 
    ( 'a' ),
    ( 'b' ),
    ( 'd' ),
    ( 'subprocess' ),
    ( 'dp' )


-- Dummy excel formulas lifted from:
-- https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/17/excel-formulas-examples/
INSERT INTO dbo.formulas( mdx )
VALUES
    ( 'a/b*d' ),
    ( 'subprocess[1].dp[2]/subprocess[1].dp[5]' ),
    ( '=).' ),
    ( '=B1+B2+B3+B4+B5' ),
    ( '=SUM(B1:B5)' ),
    ( '=2*3.' ),
    ( '=SUM(A1, A2, B5).' ),
    ( '=SUM(A1:A5).' ),
    ( '=SUM(my_name).' ),
    ( '=A2+B2' ),
    ( '=A2-B2' ),
    ( '=-A2 (changes the sign of the value in A2)' ),
    ( '=A2*B2' ),
    ( '=A2/B2' ),
    ( '=A2*10%' ),
    ( '=A2^3' ),
    ( '=A2*B2' ),
    ( '=    Equal to    =A2=B2' ),
    ( '=A2<>B2' ),
    ( '=A2>B2' ),
    ( '=A2<B2' ),
    ( '=    Greater than or equal to    =A2>=B2' ),
    ( '=    Less than or equal to   =A2<=B2' ),
    ( '=A1=B1 returns TRUE if cells A1 and B1 contain the same value (number, text or date), FALSE otherwise.' ),
    ( '=A1&" "&B1' ),
    ( '=AVERAGE(A1:A00)' ),
    ( '=SUM(A:A). Find more about whole-column and whole-row references.' ),
    ( '=IF(A1>0, "good", "bad") reads as follows: if A1 is greater than zero, return "good", otherwise "bad".' ),
    ( '=IF(A1>0; "good"; "bad").' ),
    ( '=B3:D3 C2:C4' ),
    ( '=10*5 or =SUM(A1:A10)' ),
    ( '=10*5+20 or =SUM(A1:A10)/2' ),
    ( '=). So, whatever formula you are going to write, begin by typing = either in the destination cell or in the Excel formula bar. And now, let''s have a closer look at how you can make different formulas in Excel.' ),
    ( '=$B2*$D2+$B2*$D2*$C2' ),
    ( '= amount)' ),
    ( '= VAT amount)' ),
    ( '= total' ),
    ( '=($B2*$D2+$B2*$D2*$C2)*10%' ),
    ( '=E2*10%. However, in large worksheets, it makes sense to write independently calculated formulas, so that removing a column with one formula wouldn''t break the others.' ),
    ( '=ROUND(SUM(B2:B6),0)' ),
    ( '=SUM((B2:B10>=A2:A10) * (B2:B10>0))' ),
    ( '= 0 tax' ),
    ( '= 7500 x 2% = 150' ),
    ( '= 87500 x 10% = 8750' ),
    ( '= 20000 x 20% = 4000' ),
    ( '= 12900' ),
    ( '=IF(K1<5000,0,K1-5000)*2%-IF(K1<12500,0,K1-12500)*2%+IF(K1<12500,0,K1-12500)*10%+IF(K1100000 and Percentage will be variable 20%-10%' ),
    ( '=120000' ),
    ( '=5000' ),
    ( '=A1*17%+A1' ),
    ( '=If(E1=410,"standard plan",IF(E1=500,"ENHANCED PLAN"))' ),
    ( '=IF(AND(F15>=0.26,F150.2),"Retained")' ),
    ( '=IF(AND(F15>=0.26,F15<=0.75,H15<0.2),"revised")' ),
    ( '=IF(AND(OR(F150.75),H15>0.2),"revised")' ),
    ( '=IF(AND(OR(F150.75),H15<0.2),"rejected")' ),
    ( '=IF((AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)="truetrue","retained",IF((AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)="falsefalse","rejected",IF(AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)=FALSE,"revised","")))' ),
    ( '=IF((AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)="truetrue","retained",IF((AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)="falsefalse","rejected",IF(AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)=FALSE,"revised","")))' ),
    ( '=IF((AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)="truetrue","retained",IF((AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)="falsefalse","rejected",IF(AND(F15>0.26,F15=0.20)=FALSE,"revised","")))' ),
    ( '=countifs(criteria_range,criteria,criteria_range,criteria)' ),
    ( '=countifs(A1:A10,">=1000",A1:A10,"<=5000")' ),
    ( '= Amount * (1 + %)' ),
    ( '=A1*1.1' ),
    ( '=0 when cell F34=0 but when F34>160 I need it to put what is in Cell H34.' ),
    ( '=IF(F34=0,0,IF(F34>160,H34,""))' ),
    ( '=(1500*1000)/0.7' ),
    ( '=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,SMALL(IF($E$2=$A$2:$A$9,ROW($B$2:$B$9)-1,""),ROW(A1))),"")' )
GO


-- Fix up dollar signs as they don't apply for this example ...
UPDATE dbo.formulas
SET mdx = REPLACE( mdx, '$', '' )
--OUTPUT inserted.mdx, deleted.mdx
WHERE mdx Like '%$%'
GO


-- Create some more formula records ...
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 x
UNION ALL
SELECT x + 1
FROM cte
WHERE x < 100
)
INSERT INTO dbo.formulas ( mdx )
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4000 SUBSTRING( mdx, c1.x, c2.x )
FROM cte c1, cte c2, dbo.formulas f
WHERE SUBSTRING( mdx, c1.x, c2.x ) Like '%[A-Z][1-9]%'
GO
--:exit


/*
-- Original query
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp

SELECT fcId, fc.mdx AS component, f.fId, f.mdx
INTO #tmp
FROM dbo.formulaComponents fc 
    JOIN dbo.formulas f ON f.mdx <> REPLACE( f.mdx, fc.mdx, '' )
GO
-- 7 minutes, 7,376 rows; 


-- Joe solution ...
-- 6:20, 7,376 rows
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp2

SELECT fcId, fc.mdx AS component, f.fId, f.mdx
INTO #tmp2
FROM dbo.formulaComponents fc 
    INNER JOIN dbo.formulas f ON CHARINDEX( fc.mdx, f.mdx ) > 0
OPTION ( QUERYTRACEON 8649 );
*/


/*
SELECT *
FROM dbo.formulas
WHERE fId = 66;

SELECT *
FROM #tmp
WHERE fId = 66;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.formulaComponents fc 
    JOIN dbo.formulas f ON f.mdx <> REPLACE( f.mdx, fc.mdx, '' )
WHERE f.fId = 66
GO
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.formulaParts

-- Translate all non-alpha characters into space and split the formula into its component parts
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *, TRANSLATE ( mdx, '!@#&()-[{}]:;'',?/*`~$^+=<>".%', '                             ' ) cleanMdx
FROM dbo.formulas f
--WHERE f.fId = 66
)
SELECT fId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY fId ORDER BY fId ) partNo, TRIM( [value] ) formulaPart
INTO dbo.formulaParts
FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( cleanMdx, ' ' ) x
WHERE [value] <> ''
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_formulaParts ON dbo. formulaParts ( fId, partNo )
GO

-- Now matching is easy and no false results ...
SELECT *
FROM dbo.formulas f
WHERE f.fId = 66


SELECT fp.fId, fp.formulaPart, COUNT(*) AS records
FROM dbo.formulaParts fp
    INNER JOIN dbo.formulaComponents fc ON fp.formulaPart = fc.mdx
WHERE fId = 66
GROUP BY fp.fId, fp.formulaPart



SELECT fp.fId, f.mdx AS originalFormula, fp.formulaPart, COUNT(*) AS records
FROM dbo.formulas f
    INNER JOIN dbo.formulaParts fp ON f.fId = fp.fId
    INNER JOIN dbo.formulaComponents fc ON fp.formulaPart = fc.mdx
GROUP BY fp.fId, f.mdx, fp.formulaPart
ORDER BY fp.fId, fp.formulaPart
```

Complete script available [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/bdef01436b1dafd9d93756b969254128).  Just a reminder this is just an example demonstration of a technique, not a complete production solution.  If you do not feel this addresses your problem please post some more realistic sample data, anonymised if you wish which genuinely represents your use case.

Comment: Did it run successfully?

Comment: No it didnot as we have sql server 2016 not 2017

Answer (score 0):

Using `<>` and `REPLACE` is a really rough way of getting what you want. Using `LIKE` could be a bit better, but you'll have to deal with escaping any special characters in `mdx`.

In your example data set, `#temp1` only contains individual tokens (no combined processes). If your data *actually* looks like that, you can use a string splitting function on `#temp2.mdx` and do an equi-join. I'm using [my own string splitter](https://github.com/StevenHibble/T-SQL-Tools/blob/master/SplitStringMAX) that accepts `VARCHAR(MAX)` values. It's based on [Jeff Moden's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.mdx
     , t2.mdx
FROM #temp2 t2
     CROSS APPLY Tools.SplitStringMAX (mdx, '/') ss
     JOIN #temp1 t1
       ON ss.String = t1.mdx;
```

Comment: I can not use string spilt be because the formula is not as simple as it looks

Comment: It can be anything like it can have if condition in it and also can be of any length like if(a/b>2,a/b*100,a*100/c) it is just an assumption but what i am trying to say is we can Not split string in that manner

Comment: How about what's in `#temp1`? Is that simple (e.g. `A`, `B`)? Or can it contain *any* sub-expression (e.g. "a/b*100")?